# dotdotdot originalContent with multiple divs

Tags: jquery, html, ellipsis

I have several divs displaying text, and I managed to have these divs correctly wrapped with the dotdotdot plugin.

what I want is to display a "read more" link after the wrapped div, and display the full original content of the div when the user clicks on the link.

The problem is that I didn't manage to make a proper use of the `triggerHandler(originalContent)` function (`div.html()` returns the wrapped text), which is mainly due, I believe, to the fact that all wrapped divs share a same CSS class.

Here's my HTML :

```
<section>
  <article>
   <h3>title<h3>
   <div>paragraph to be wrapped</div>
   <a class="readmore">Read more</a>
  </article>
  <article>
   <h3>title<h3>
   <div>paragraph to be wrapped</div>
   <a class="readmore">Read more</a>
  </article>
</section>
```

I have more than 2 divs, but you get the picture

jQuery to wrap the divs (works fine) :

```
$('article').each(function(){
   $(this).find('div').dotdotdot({after: '.readmore'})
});
```

and last but not least, the code to retrieve the original content of the wrapped div (displaying the popup is not an issue)

```
$('.readmore').click(function(){
  //first I want to target the div right above the clicked .readmore link
  var targetedDiv = $(event.target).parent().children('div');

  // Then I try to get the div's original content through the dotdotdot function
  var targetedDivHTML = targetedDiv.triggerHandler('originalContent');

});
```

but when I alert targetedDivHTML to see if I get the right content, I get [object Object] or an error message saying triggerHandler() is not defined.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Solved. putting the $('.readmore').click function within the $('.article').each loop works :

```
$('article').each(function(){
   $(this).find('div').dotdotdot({after: '.readmore'})

  $(this).click(function(){
    var content = $(this).find('div').triggerHandler('originalContent');
    $('.fulltextdiv').append(content);
    $('.fulltextdiv').show();

  });
});
```

The popup can then be opened by clicking the entire article, and not only the read more link, but it still works ok